# Differentiation - AS Level Maths (Edexcel Specification)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A curve has equation $y=12x^{\frac12}-x^{\frac32}$.
>   Show that $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac32x^{-\frac12}(4-x)$$

This is taken from Edexcel C1 maths for As level. I can usually do the other differentiation questions, but this one is really baffling me. The answer key in the book doesn't provide sufficient steps or explanation for me to understand.

I can differentiate it, but can't get it into the form required by the question.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you differentiate it?

Comment: Have you expanded their answer? If you have differentiated correctly this should be a simple factorisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by factoring out $\frac{3}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}
&= 12\cdot \frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}-1} - \frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}-1} = \\
& =6x^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}
It is obvious, how to factor out $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ from $6x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, also $\frac{3}{2}$ from $-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. You simply get $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 6$ and $\frac{3}{2}\cdot(-x^{\frac{1}{2}})$. Now you just need to realize, that it holds $c = \frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{b}{a} c$, and $x^{d+e} = x^d \cdot x^e$ (you need to satisfy some conditions, like $a\neq 0 \neq b$ etc. That should be without any problems,). So you can continue
\begin{align*}
6x^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}
&= x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 6 + \frac{3}{2}(-x^{\frac{1}{2}})=\\
&= x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot6 + \frac{3}{2}(-x^{1-\frac{1}{2}}) =\\
&=\frac{3}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot 6 + \frac{3}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(-x)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(4-x)
\end{align*}

Skipping the step $-x^{1-\frac{1}{2}} = -x\cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$

Comment: Nice, thanks very much. Looks like I need to study my rules of working with indices.